# Spring RestTemplate ignores package-info.java

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, jaxb

i have generated a some classes from an xsd using the 'xjc' command.

The problem i have is that in the generated package there is a package-info file with only the @XmlSchema annotation on the package:

e.g.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2/plazaapi.xsd", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.xxx.bolapp.dto;
```

I got two problems: First the marshaller always throws an exception when unmarshalling:

```
exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not unmarshal to [class nl.minc.bolapp.dto.Orders]: unexpected element (uri:"https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2/plazaapi.xsd", local:"Orders"). Expected elements are <{}Orders>; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2/plazaapi.xsd", local:"Orders"). Expected elements are <{}Orders>
```

I can remove that when setting the namepace directly on the @XmlRoot
As soon as I do that, the initial Orders get parsed correctly. The problem I encounter then is that the children are null, where there should be data.

The problem now is mostly that the child is null, but I suspect it has something to do with the namespace.

**EDIT 1**
The Problem with the null children goes away when posting the namespace
in every XmlElement, sop this is definitely a direct causality.

I post the generated class and the xml:

Class:

```
package com.xxx.bolapp.dto;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "order"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Orders")
public class Orders
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "Order")
    protected List<Orders.Order> order;
....
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "orderId",
    "dateTimeCustomer",
    "dateTimeDropShipper",
    "customerDetails",
    "orderItems"
})
public static class Order
    implements Serializable
{
....
}
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders xmlns="https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2/plazaapi.xsd">
<Order>
 <OrderId>4123456789</OrderId>
 <DateTimeCustomer>2017-02-09T12:39:48.000+01:00</DateTimeCustomer>
 <DateTimeDropShipper>2017-02-09T12:39:48.000+01:00</DateTimeDropShipper>
 <CustomerDetails>
   <ShipmentDetails>
     <SalutationCode>02</SalutationCode>
     <Firstname>Billie</Firstname>
     <Surname>Van der Bol.com</Surname>
     <Streetname>Dorpstraat</Streetname>
     <Housenumber>1</Housenumber>
     <HousenumberExtended>B</HousenumberExtended>
     <ZipCode>1111 ZZ</ZipCode>
     <City>Utrecht</City>
     <CountryCode>NL</CountryCode>
     <Email>2awq74td4z4mizmx6dcdbsdbdcna@verkopen.bol.com</Email>
     <Company>bol.com</Company>
   </ShipmentDetails>
   <BillingDetails>
     <SalutationCode>02</SalutationCode>
     <Firstname>Billie</Firstname>
     <Surname>van der Bol.com</Surname>
     <Streetname>Dorpstraat</Streetname>
     <Housenumber>1</Housenumber>
     <HousenumberExtended>B</HousenumberExtended>
     <ZipCode>1111 ZZ</ZipCode>
     <City>Utrecht</City>
     <CountryCode>NL</CountryCode>
     <Email>2awq74td4z4mizmx6dcdbsdbdcna@verkopen.bol.com</Email>
     <Company>bol.com</Company>
   </BillingDetails>
 </CustomerDetails>
 <OrderItems>
   <OrderItem>
     <OrderItemId>2012345678</OrderItemId>
     <EAN>5412810182312</EAN>
     <OfferReference>BOLCOM00123</OfferReference>
     <Title>Basicxl - Rijdende Wekker - Kunststof - 16x11cm - Zwart</Title>
     <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     <OfferPrice>27.95</OfferPrice>
     <TransactionFee>5.18</TransactionFee>
     <LatestDeliveryDate>2017-02-10+01:00</LatestDeliveryDate>
     <OfferCondition>NEW</OfferCondition>
     <CancelRequest>false</CancelRequest>
     <FulfilmentMethod>FBR</FulfilmentMethod>
   </OrderItem>
 </OrderItems>
 </Order>
</Orders>
```

Comment: your Orders class is inside the same package what you mentioned in package-info.java ?

Comment: yes, it is all autogenerated by xjc